# Are cyclists inconvenienced by support car exhausts?

Tags: cycling

During a road bicycle race, like Giro d'Italia or Tour de France, cyclists have to share the road with the support cars and often ride just behind them. Don’t they mind the exhausts from the cars, or do the exhausts inconvenience them? Do the cars have any special equipment to reduce the harmfulness of their exhausts (or, at least, is there regulation requiring the cars to fulfill some stricter norms)?

Comment: The easiest way to reduce emissions for the bikers is to require electric cars - didn't notice any of those while watching the Tour de France. However, since Renault and Nissan are partners, maybe that can provide Leafs to the teams! They might not have sufficient range for a full ride up and down hills though.

Comment: There is also another thing - you're not allowed to ride behind a car for a long time.

Comment: I love it when a mechanic hangs out the car window trying to fix a deraulier as they ride along.  When I see that, I shake my head at their insanity!

Comment: @MariusBalaban Moto-pacing!  Fun to do with trucks in traffic, when it works!  I love riding on highways with paved shoulders.  The draft you get from the trucks is amazing.  Its like being sucked along for a bit.

Comment: With Skoda being a sponsor, they use brand new cars which have the lowest possible emissions.   No car-based sponsor is going to allow any vehicle that makes them look bad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Having ridden in traffic, on 6 lanes roads, even on highways (with shoulders) I can say the exhaust is a non-issue.  Considering how few support cars there actually are, compared to a 6 lane road, I would say it is not even noticeable.

Comment: They probably care for about driving style of the drivers: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mYPDAry-A-s

Comment: Bernhard:   I think the guys driving the cars at TdF are nuts, but that is a different issue.  :)